# Idiomatic way to convert class method to proc in ruby

Tags: ruby

Suppose I want to describe `Kernel.puts` using a Proc. How would I do this ?

I can think of a number of possibilities;

```
Proc.new do |*args| Kernel.puts *args end
:puts.to_proc.curry[Kernel] # doesn't work, returns `nil` as puts is varargs
```

But both are quite verbose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Would `method` be what you're looking for? It can let you save a method to a variable.

```
2.1.0 :003 > m = Kernel.method(:puts)
 => #<Method: Kernel.puts>
2.1.0 :004 > m.call('hi')
hi
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just want [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-method):

```
meth = Kernel.method(:puts)
meth["hello"]
# => hello
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the receiver object as first parameter, and actual argument as subsequent parameters.

```
:puts.to_proc.call(Kernel, "Hi")
#=> Hi
```

I found this article - [RUBY: SYMBOL#TO_PROC IS A LAMBADASS](http://www.monadzoo.com/blog/2013/08/12/ruby-symbol-to-proc-is-a-lambadass/) - to be quite informative on behavior of lambdas returned by `Symbol#to_proc`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the answer got accepted got accepted, as it is not what was asked. That answer takes the string as the argument, whereas the OP wanted to pass `Kernel`. So I will give my answer.

You cannot do that using `Symbol` to `Proc`. I think you are confusing the receiver and the arguments. `Symbol` to `Proc` creates a proc that takes the receiver as the variable, not its arguments. And, currying modifies the arity of the arguments; it has nothing to do with the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc = proc {  |*args| Kernel.puts(args) }
```

or with a lambda

```
proc = ->(*args) {Kernel.puts(args) }
```